# Redis slow read performance

Tags: performance, caching, redis

I installed Redis to evaluate if I could use it to cache collection of objects; each key contains a time series of updates, each update is a byte[5000]. I am surprised with the results of a simple test I ran- I inserted 1000 arrays; each is a byte[5000]. Reading the complete list running LRANGE on the machine locally takes 20s to complete. 
I tested by varying the number of byte[5000] objects  I retrieved, and the time to retrieve was proportionate to the size of the data requested o(n), as expected. 
Any one has an opinion on the amount of time it's taking to complete such an  operations?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble following you description exaclty, but if it helps, the following takes 0.05 seconds:

```
1000.times do
    redis.lpush 'ourlist', 'kjlkjlk' * 5000
end
start = Time.now
redis.lrange 'ourlist', 0, 1000
puts Time.now - start
=> 0.052775
```